# Python - TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newbie here. I am trying to operate on lists which contain floating point numbers. `avg` is a list parameter that is returned from a different method. However, when I tried doing the following, it throws me an error that float() should have a string or a number and not a list. `avg1` should contain a copy of the lists with float-type numbers instead of lists right? I tried a few edits I read on other posts with similar titles, but couldn't solve this.
Just starting out so kindly tell me where I am going wrong.

```
def movingavg(EMA,avg):     
    EMA=[]
    avg1 = [float(i) for i in avg]
    EMA[:3] = avg1[:3]
    for i,j in zip(EMA[2:],avg1[3:]):
        a =float(i)*0.67 + float(j)*0.33
        EMA.append(a)
    return EMA
```

The error that I get is as follows :

```
avg1 = [float(i) for i in avg]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Using Python 3.4

Comment: Please post an example of what ``avg`` looks like. Seems as if it is a list of lists or sth alike.

Comment: @jbndlr it is a list with numbers taken from a column in a pandas dataframe. 

[[12312188.0], [6055962.0], [2753511.0], [3216789.0], [3554074.0], [4638837.0], [7064825.0], [4162710.0], [3262018.0], [3913376.0], [3945705.0]] 
I have included a few values out of the many.

Comment: See, you got a list of lists there. Change your float-cast to ``float(i[0])`` if it's always in this shape.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `avg1 = [float(i) for i in avg]` use below code.

```
avg1 = []
for i in avg:
    for j in i:
        avg1.append(float(j))
```

or can use below list comprehension.

```
avg1 = [float(i)  for val in avg for i in val]
```

Comment: Using a list comprehension would be a lot more concise for this.

Comment: I am writing it. Just posted answer. Will edit in minute. :)

Comment: The result of the list comprehension will produce a single list rather than keeping the data structure of the OP.

Comment: Yups. I think the code which is executed after this line of code, requires single list and not list of list. That's why I created single list.

Comment: Initially I have written comprehension similar like yours. But then checked the code and changed it.

Comment: @SastryGosukonda - Please check my answer and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: @DineshPundkar Thank you, it did help in removing the error, I am able to view it as a single list of float values. But the function is still not able to do what I want it to. Guess there's a logical error with this. 
EMA is supposed to get updated with the calculated values from avg, but it isn't printing beyond 4 values.

Comment: Can you please tell the expected output?

Comment: @DineshPundkar EMA is essentially the expected moving average of the entries from the list avg. So with each iterated value of avg, EMA is supposed to be updated with the moving average. But it's not printing beyond 4 values.

Comment: @DineshPundkar am I slicing them wrong? While iterating through them.

Comment: I sorted it out, was a logical error indeed. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check return type of avg I think it's return type is list's of list.

Comment: I did, and you're right, it's a list of lists. But how do I cast it to float for use?

Comment: @AmanJaiswal that isn't actually using the `map` function though, that's just an embedded list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a list of lists to float, you need to use two list comprehensions, like this:

```
avg1 = [[float(i) for i in val] for val in avg]
```

Comment: This will result again in list of list.